# Error including QT header files without .h extension

Tags: qt, cmake

My colleague wrote a code in QT where he includes

```
#include<QtWidgets>
```

I have the task of writing cmake files for all the libraries and executables built.

I get an error saying the header wasn't found. I know if I change that to the other header which has .h extension it will work but is there a way out where I won't have to change any of his code and still be able to detect these includes ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(myproject)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

SET(SRC
  src/main.cpp
  src/video_player.cpp
  src/video_widget.cpp
  src/video_widget_surface.cpp
)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(myproject ${SRC} ${myproject_HEADERS_MOC})
```

Comment: It's `<QtWidgets>`, you do not need to put .h at the end.  Can't you just do a search and replace on the code base?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to change anything in the code base. I want to have cmake include the right headers, exactly like qmake does.

Comment: What version of Qt are you working with? And what is the version your colleague uses? Afaik QtWidgets is Qt5, while QtGui was the equivalent in Qt4. (Well, not really equivalent, but that's too long for a comment).

Comment: Yeah we are using QT5

Comment: @drescherjm Your includes are _not_ case sensitive!?

Comment: @navderm Okay, so both the same version? My hunch was that you were still on Qt4. So the problem here is one of a missing path. Not of a missing file. (Did you check the case-sensitivity?)

Comment: Yeah I did. The header files have correct case. It is actually being used properly and its installing correctly using qmake.

Comment: one more thing I noticed is 
if I use 
find_package(Qt REQUIRED)
it includes but if I use 
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED)
it fails

Comment: @cmannett85. I did not notice that however in my case it would still work since windows is not case sensitive..

Comment: Do you have a very recent version of CMake installed. I believe support for Qt5 was only in a very recent version. 2.8.10.X?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you either need patches or cmake-2.8.11rcX for Qt5 support.

Comment: hmm ok. i'll try to use latest cmake. i am using 2.6 right now

Comment: Ok. So I installed latest cmake 2.8.10. I still seem to have the problem where I can't find the right headers. I have added my cmakefile here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is buggy, it should ready `#include <QtWidgets>` (notice lowercase `t`). There is no way to make this work without changing it or ugly hacks.